# How to install a Delphi component package from the command line?

Tags: delphi, installation, components

I am preparing an installer ([Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup)) to install my component package into Delphi XE without having to manually fiddle in the IDE.

How do I install a Delphi component package (for example, MyComponent.bpl) into Delphi without having to manually do it via the 'Install Packages' menu item? Is it a registry key?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep, registry is your friend.

Packages:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\Known IDE Packages
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\Known Packages
```

IIRC Known IDE Packages is for IDE extensions, and Known Packages for components (on the Tool Palette)

Library paths are in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\Library
```

Note:

- `<Borcadero>` stands for Borland, CodeGear or Embarcadero, depending on your Delphi version.
- `<version>` is the IDE version, ie 7.0 for Delphi 2010.

Comment: 'Borcadero' - I love it :-)

Comment: On Delphi versions using MsBuild there's another registry key that's used to tell Delphi it's Library path has changed. Can't look it up right now because I'm in the middle of re-installing my Windows OS, but will revisit once I've got my stuff working.

Comment: @Cosmin: that would be great, didn't know it existed. Good luck with the re-install...

Comment: The registry key is: `HCU\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\Globals` and the value is `ForceEnvOptionsUpdate`. I always set that to `1` if I altered the installed package list or modified search paths in any way.

Comment: @Cosmin: +1 for deep insight. HTF did you find that out?