# delphi 7, installed component is hidden on installation

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7, custom-component

i am working on a component for `delphi 7` and for quick installation without having to touch the `IDE` i am making a simple installer according to this SO answer by  [Marjan Venema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813090/1051198).

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      sDelphi7PackageName : string;
      sDelphi7Path,fileSource,fileDest : string;
      sDelphi7packBPL,sDelphi7PathMenuBPL  : string;
    begin
       sDelphi7Path:=ReadRegistryValues('\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0',FALSE,'RootDir',1,TRUE);{<-- returns the 'C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7' }

      {#1. Install .bpl}
      sDelphi7BPL:=sDelphi7Path+'\Projects\Bpl\Pack.bpl';
      WriteValueToRegisTry('\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Known   Packages',FALSE,sDelphi7BPL,'Delphi 7 compo Bpl File'); {<-- writes to the registry}

      fileSource:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Packages\comPack.bpl';
      fileDest:=sDelphi7BPL;
      CopyFile(PChar(fileSource), PChar(fileDest), False);
      end;
```

This works fine 
![enter image description here][2]
`C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\Pack.bpl`. 
 but the component installed id `hidden`

can anyone tell me how to `unhide` the `component` on installation?

**EDIT**

may be useful:

1) i already have the `bpl` file of the component so i am copying directly to the `delphi 7` directory `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl` and modifying the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Known Packages`.

2) the `register` procedure of the component

```
 implementation
 procedure Register;
  begin
      RegisterComponents('comp', [Tcomp]);
  end;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you've put in your `procedure Register` method inside of your package?

Comment: @LaKraven: I'm afraid in this case the Register procedure is not relevant. My understanding of the question is that the OP is attempting to install components by means of some direct registry manipulation.

Comment: @LaKraven `procedure Register` addded

Comment: @menjaraz: nope the Register procedure is relevant. The windows registry is just to make the IDE aware of the bpl's to load. The register procedure is what the IDE executes after loading the bpl to put the components on a page of the palet.

Comment: @PresleyDias did you declare the Register procedure in the interface section as well? And with the correct capitalization? That is a capital R and the rest lowercase? This is the one place in which Delphi is (needs to be) case-sensitive,

Comment: @MarjanVenema : yes `procedure Register;` in the `interface` section

Comment: In that case I am stumped. Should work. I do see that in your WriteValueToRegisTry statement, there are extra spaces between "Known" and "Packages", but maybe that's just from copy/pasting?

Comment: @MarjanVenema : [TOndrej's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481291/1051198) answer worked and thank you for your original answer also

Comment: @Marjan Venema: I thought that it was only needed for the sake of creation of the entries on the registry when registering the components using the IDE and basta. Is that the reason for Classes.RegisterComponentsProc (Handler used within Classes.RegisterComponents procedure) making the *Register* procedure somewhat "polymorphic" ?

Comment: @menjaraz: Polymorphism doesn't come into it. RegisterComponentsProc is simply a variable that holds the address of a procedure with the same signature as RegisterComponents (without declaring an explicit type for it). I expect that this var will get its value set by the IDE before the Register procedures in the units of a package are called (if one exists for the unit). You could think of it as a call back provided by the IDE.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: You are right, polymorphism is for the OOP paradigma and it's actually a call back used by the IDE: I remember now of an article of Rudy Velthuis related to *compinst* where he attempted in vain to register a component from code by calling directely the Register procedure (BPL). Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the registry, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Palette`, find the entry named `'comp.Hidden'` and edit it to remove the class name of your component (or delete the entry altogether).

Comment: +1,it worked..!!,great.. but can you tell me why it was `hidden`?

Comment: I guess somebody pressed the "Hide" button in the "Palette Properties" dialog.

Comment: nope..i am the only one on my system..and i really didnt press the `hide` button.

Comment: today i tried installation of the component on different system, it got installed but it was again `hidden` :(