# Delphi, Compile and install component in a bpg via command line

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7, bpl

I have a bpg, and within this bpg have a list of 8 dpk's / bpl, I need to build all these dpk's via command line, and install these dpks too .. How can I do this via the command line?

The idea is to make a installer like jedi components, I've been analyzing it but did not understand the operation.

Comment: What part of the problem are you stuck on?

Comment: on the command line code to do this, compile all dpks e then install all dpks.

Comment: Compile all the DCUs with a call to dcc32. And for the rest, there is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813024/how-to-install-a-delphi-component-package-from-the-command-line

Comment: To install packages you need to register them in the Windows Registry for the given Delphi configuration (each Delphi version may have few configurations, usually a single one used though). I think you are to analyze both JCL and JVCL installers, and you will find where they do registry access. Maybe those would be units using d:\DelphiProjects\Libs\JCL\jcl\source\common\JclIDEUtils.pas  OTOH, if to skip installing, then you probably can "autobuild" the whole BPG at once - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options

Comment: A useful shortcut is to build each package in the IDE with the settings you need.  Then examine the switches and options generated in the .cfg and .dof files.  This should give you the correct commandline options to dcc32

Comment: Thanks the first i make :D. Build all packages, now i need to know what is the command to realy "install" the builded packages..